# Adding a column frame a data frame to a spatial polygons data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, polygon

I have two files including the `covid_provincial.csv` and `Co_adm1.zip` files. The first one consists of number of COVID confirmed in a country. The second one is the shapefile of boundaries of the country. I imported them into R and stored them into `a` and `b` objects writing the following codes:

```
a<-read.csv("the directory of my system which includes covid_provincial.csv")

b<-readOGR(dsn = "the directory (the folder) of my system which includes shape files")
```

I want to add a variable with name Province to the `b` object. Finally, I want to merge the `a` to the `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Taking into account @Robert's suggestion, it is better to omit the explicit call to `@data`.
You can add a column to your shp file by:

```
b$Province<-c("provinces", "names", "ecc")
```

or  like this if you now that the order of Province in `a` correspond to the element of `b`

```
b$Province<-a$Province
```

then merge `a` to `b` with merge:

```
b <-merge(b,a,by="Province")
```

This should work. However, there are different way to do the same things.

**EDIT**
I add an example with some data. This example is not reproducible but should drive you in the right direction:

```
library(raster)
shp <- shapefile("dati/Limiti_2016_WGS84_Italia/regioni/basilicata_provincie.shp")
plot(shp)
```

[image]

```
data.frame(shp)

  SHAPE_Leng SHAPE_Area   X_sum
0   593511.8 6593536923 4751953
1   367848.1 3479205085 1371840
```

create a toy `data.frame`

```
df <- data.frame(provincie=c("A","B"),pop=c(10000,20000),covid=c(2000,3500))
shp$provincie <- df$provincie
```

now the shp looks like this

```
  SHAPE_Leng SHAPE_Area   X_sum provincie
0   593511.8 6593536923 4751953         A
1   367848.1 3479205085 1371840         B
```

finally, we can `merge` the two

```
shp <- merge(shp,df,by="province")
 data.frame(shp)
```

the output is:

```
  provincie SHAPE_Leng SHAPE_Area   X_sum   pop covid
1         A   593511.8 6593536923 4751953 10000  2000
2         B   367848.1 3479205085 1371840 20000  3500
```

but the class of `shp` is preserved

```
> class(shp)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

Comment: thank you for your explanations, could you please explain what are `"provinces"`, `"names"`, `"ecc"` in the vector `c("provinces", "names", "ecc")`?

Comment: the names of your Provinces, in your case `c("EC", "FS", "GT", "KZ", "LM", "MP"
)` taken form dataset `a`

Comment: I did your hints, but why is not the class of b@data a spatial polygons dataframe? (please see my next comment). I need b@data as a spatial polygons data frame and not as a data frame!

Comment: `> class(b@data)
[1] "data.frame"
> dput(head(b@data))
structure(list(Province = character(0), ID_0 = character(0), 
    ISO = character(0), NAME_0 = character(0), ID_1 = character(0), 
    NAME_1 = character(0), TYPE_1 = character(0), ENGTYPE_1 = character(0), 
    NL_NAME_1 = character(0), VARNAME_1 = character(0), Cases = integer(0), 
    Population = numeric(0)), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: b@data is just the slot where the attribute table of the shp file is stored, and its class is `data.frame`. However, after change the `b@data` slot the object `b` should remain of the same class.

Comment: The results of merge is as follow:
`> b@data <-merge(b@data,a,by="Province")
> b@data
 [1] Province   ID_0       ISO        NAME_0     ID_1       NAME_1     TYPE_1    
 [8] ENGTYPE_1  NL_NAME_1  VARNAME_1  Cases      Population
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`

Comment: after using your codes the result of `b@Province` is `character(0)`. Why character is 0?

Comment: This: `merge.data.frame(shp@data,df,by="province")` is terribly wrong because the order of the records may change when you do that. It should be `merge(shp, df, by="province")`, Also elsewhere the code would be much better if you omitted the `@data` slot ---- end users should normally not touch slots. Just do `b$Province` )` as intended by the package developers.  Also, why use example data that we do not have? That is not very useful. There is plenty of good example data that comes with R that you can use..

Comment: I've tried to answer with the notation of the OP, but since it seemed to me there was a problem of understanding rather than of code I ran my example step by step on non-reproducible data, just to show the output. In general, I know it's a bad idea to create non-reproducible examples. Regarding the use of @data, I didn't know that it is better not to use the slots directly. To me, It seems a clear way of working with shp files. I will edit my answer to take into account your comments. However, in my first example the solution proposed was `merge(shp, df, by="province")`

Comment: You still assign to `b@data <- merge()` where it should be `b <- merge()`. Also, instead of showing `b@data` it really should be `data.frame(b)` --- even if, perhaps, a bit pedantic. If you used a reproducible example that would be be clear and much more helpful to the OP and anyone else coming here.